# How to get rid of grub error on aptitude safe-upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, grub, aptitude

This is a new ubuntu 10.04 root server at the hoster. I did the initial

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

Now I am confronted with this message each time I run `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`

```
root@Ubuntu-1004-lucid-64-minimal ~ # sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  grub-pc 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
Setting up grub-pc (1.98-1ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up grub-pc (1.98-1ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
```

How can I fix this / make the message go away in a safe way?

Comment: Is this a Virtual Private Server (VPS)? If so, is it based on OpenVZ/Virtuozzo virtualization technology, or something else?

Comment: No, it is actually a real root server, no virtualization involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to support and they fixed it. I believe they had not properly managed their package mirrors.